# Twilio: Messaging is unavailable for this phone number

Tags: sms, twilio

I have a Twilio test account for now. I got assigned a Belgian phone number and I validated my own mobile number. I'm trying to send simple SMS message from my assigned Twilio number to my mobile number but that doesn't work.

The dashboard indicates "Messaging is unavailable for this phone number." But in the messaging FAQ (https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/which-countries-does-twilio-have-phone-numbers-in-and-what-are-their-capabilities), it is mentioned that Domestic and Global SMS is enabled for Belgium.

1) Why can't I send SMS messages if my country is listed as SMS enabled?
2) Is it because I have a trial account and will it work once I upgrade?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer to your questions:

1) Why can't I send SMS messages if my country is listed as SMS enabled? 
For this, I can say may there something wrong in your code. 
If your country is listed in SMS enabled countries, then it will work there is no issue.

2) Is it because I have a trial account and will it work once I upgrade?
From an trial account You can [send SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) to the number with you registeted. To other numbers it will work after you upgrade your account.

If you share your code then will be easy to help you.

You can refer this, I think it will help you.
http://phpobserver.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/build-sms-text-message-into-your-web-apps-twilio-api/

Comment: Hi, there are no available numbers for Belgiun right now. I have temporarily used an US number and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the phone number you have configured is a Belgian phone number.  Twilio currently doesn't support sending SMS from a Belgian phone number to a Belgian phone number.

The solution is that you have to configure Twilio to to send the SMS from a US number to the Belgian phone number.

If you're on a trial account, release the assigned Belgian phone number.  Then under number management section in your dashboard you will see:

> You don't have any Twilio numbers, but your first number is on us. [Get it now](https://www.twilio.com/signup/number).

Click on "Get it now".  Then, if you verified using a Belgian phone number it will by default show you a phone number from Belgium.  Click on "**Choose your own number**".  Then go to the dropdown box and change the country to US such that the proposed phone numbers are US numbers.

With the US numbers you will see that they are capable of sending SMS to Belgian phone numbers.  The only disadvantage of this approach is that the SMS will appear to be coming from US.  But depending on your application this may not be such a big problem.

Comment: I don't get the message "your first number is on us". All it says is "You don't have any Twilio Numbers. Buy a new Twilio Number or port a number"

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Its likely that the Belgian number that you were assigned when you created your account only has voice enabled on it, but the good news is that Twilio does have SMS enabled Belgian numbers.

When you click the "Buy a Number" button, you can tell Twilio to only show you numbers that are SMS-enabled:

[image: SMS Filter]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, doing that search does not reveal any SMS-enabled phone number for Belgium. Searching with "Any" finds about 10 voice-enabled phone number only.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of posting, there were no SMS enabled Belgian numbers available. It seems that the pool of Belgian numbers that support both SMS and Voice is very limited and you need to be lucky to get one.